# Protractor: how to compare full page screenshot with protractor-image-comparison

Tags: image, protractor, comparison

I've found this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-image-comparison from wswebcreation-nl, which I find interesting and useful in my case. However I'm not that good at Protractor yet, I have problem comparing full page screens. Comparing element images however works, but still throws an error.

Config.js

```
    onPrepare: function() {
            // protractor-image-comparison module
            const protractorImageComparison = require('protractor-image-comparison');
            browser. protractorImageComparison = new protractorImageComparison(
                {
                    autoSaveBaseline: true,
                    baselineFolder: '../baseline/',
                    screenshotPath: '../actual_screenshots/',
                    debug: true,
                    disableCSSAnimation: true,
                    nativeWebScreenshot: true,
                    blockOutStatusBar: true,
                    ignoreColors: true
                }
            );
    ...
    }
```

Spec.js

```
// page objects
var landingPage = require('../landing_page/landing_page.js');

describe('User is on landing page', function() {
it('should see landing page screenshot compared successfully to the baseline', function() {
        // initialize page object
        var landing = new landingPage();

        browser.protractorImageComparison.saveElement(landing.registerButton, 'imageA');

        expect(browser.protractorImageComparison.checkElement(landing.registerButton, 'imageB')).toEqual('imageA');

    });
});
```

Once test is finished, I have screenshots of the element in all folders (baseline, actual_screenshots/actual and actual_screenshots/diff.

Error from console:

> Spec started .   User is on landing page
>       √ should see register button
>
> ############################################## compareOptions =  { isScreen: false,   ignoreAntialiasing: false,   ignoreColors: true,
>
> ignoreRectangles: [],   ignoreTransparentPixel: false }
>
> #
>
> F    × should see landing page screenshot compared successfully to the
>   baseline
>         - Expected 0 to equal 'imageA'.

Comment: When I use `browser.protractorImageComparison.saveFullPageScreen('imageA'); expect(browser.protractorImageComparison.checkFullPageScreen('imageB')).toEqual('imageA');` then the error is **Failed: browser.protractorImageComparison.saveFullPageScreen is not a function**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out by myself that it doesn't work in the way I was expecting, because I didn't understood how expect should work. So instead of `.toEqual('imageA');` this should be written like `.toEqual(0);` which means 0 % difference. Something that isn't very clear from the docs for noobs like me. Otherwise image comparison works as intended and flawlessly.